# Tracing changes to window.location in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have a webapp which is doing a weird, wrong, unexpected redirection through JavaScript (I checked that by disabling JavaScript in the browser. Redirection doesn't happen). I've also checked all the JavaScript code for window.location being set and put breakpoints on it, but it still didn't tell me who did the redirect.

I don't want to add processing before or after redirections, I need to know which code triggered the redirection so I can disabled it.

Comment: Look for `window.location`, `window.navigate("***")`, `document.location`

Comment: And `history.pushState`...

Comment: And `history.replaceState` :)

Answer (score 0):

There's several methods to do navigation in Javascript. Check

- window.location or document.location
- window.navigate (only in some browsers)
- window.history

See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history on history, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location on window.location